# Показ картинок с задержкой в PictureBox

Tags: c#

Не могу понять, что в моем методе неправильно (показывает мне только последнюю картинку, и на этом всё):

```
public void PhotoUrl(ReadOnlyCollection<Post> wall) 
{
    foreach (var post in wall)
    {
        var photo = post.Attachment.Instance as Photo;
        if (photo == null)
            continue;
        string photoUrl = photo.Photo604.AbsoluteUri;
        if (photoUrl != null)
        {
            pictureBox1.ImageLocation = photoUrl;
            if (pictureBox1.Visible == true) {
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

Вызываю по клику в `main`:

```
PhotoUrl(wall);
```

Comment: Кстати, `pictureBox1.Visible == true` вполне можно заменить на `pictureBox1.Visible`

Comment: Пользовательский интерфейс не прорисовывается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Application.DoEvents();
```

это после показа каждой картинки
А вообще юзай таймеры.

Дело в том, что при изменении изображения в систему постится событие на перерисовку, но так как у тебя синхронный цикл, события не начинают обрабатываться. Как только цикл проходит и управление возвращается приложению, начинают отрабатывать события. В итоге ты видишь только последнюю картинку.

Таймер в этом случае правильнее был бы. Т.к. таймер постит событие и возвращает управление системе, А Thread.sleep синхронно ждет.

Comment: Спасибо! Но куда это вписать?

Comment: после pictureBox1.ImageLocation = photoUrl; впиши

Comment: @shatoidil после `pictureBox1.ImageLocation = photoUrl;`